# How to detect the user when using a jwt token (Slim-jwt-auth)

Tags: authentication, jwt, slim

I'm currently using Slim with slim-jwt-auth.

My project is based on the slim-api-skeleton (https://github.com/tuupola/slim-api-skeleton).
I need to allow a route only for the user who has created the token.

I've done it with the following code:

```
        //check if it is the right user
        $user = \User::find($args["uid"]);

        $token = $request->getHeader('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');                
        $token = str_replace("Bearer ", "", $token);
        $secret = getenv("JWT_SECRET");
        $decoded = JWT::decode($token[0], $secret, array("HS256"));

        if ($decoded->sub != $user->email) 
        {
            throw new ForbiddenException("User not allowed to read.");
        }
```

Is it correct ? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one way to do it. Although I would not parse the token manually. By default the parsed values of JWT are stored in `$request->token` attribute. Using this you can shorten your code to the following.

```
$app->get("/user/{uid}", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    $user = \User::find($arguments["uid"]);

    $token = $request->getAttribute("token");

    if ($token->sub !== $user->email) ) {
        throw new ForbiddenException("User not allowed to read.");
    }
});
```

You can change this behaviour using [attribute](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth#attribute) setting.

Comment: Thanks ... it works.
I have just changed the way to get the token, because directly using $request->token->sub doesn't work for me. So, I've used the following way:
    $token = $request->getAttribute("token");

    if ($token->sub !== $user->email)  ...